# ASP.NET AJAX AutoCompleteExtender inside ModalPopupExtender

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services

i have ASP.NET login page in AJAX ModalPopupExtender. one of the text fields is company of the user. for this i used AJAX AutoCompleteExtender with web service.
it works well but the issue is that i see the complition list in the back of the ModalPopupExtender.(see image).is it possible to fix it?

[image]

Comment: check the z-index of the overlay and the z-index of the list.
The list must have a higher z-index

Comment: i tried it but the result is the same.add z-index of 99999 for list and z-index of 1 to overlay...

Comment: check if the z-index does not get overriden by another css! z-index of the list.

Comment: i checked it and z-index is not overriden.

Comment: can u make a small jsfiddle?

Comment: i dont know what is it...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: thanks...fixed with  z-index:999999 !important to complition list;

Comment: You have the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954892/asp-net-ajax-autocompleteextender-control-appears-behind-other-controls